# Flushing Magento Caches with Magerun

Tags: cache, cli

While learning about the diverse caches in Magento (e.g. per [Various Magento Cache flushing methods](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/18582/4115), I was wondering which of these Magerun supports on how the commands would look like?

Answer (score 4):

Magerun supports differentiated cache handling from the command-line:

**Flush and refresh:**

Magerun supports both to flush (empty the cache) or refresh (cleaning the invalidated cache keys) the cache(s).

The wording is *`flush`* to flush/empty the cache and *`clean`* to refresh/clean.

Next to flushing and refreshing the cache, caches can be en- and disabled, listed, viewed, reported and there is a whole suite for benchmarking the caches. All those commands are under the *`cache:`* namespace.

Example:

```
user@host ~$ n98-magerun.phar cache:clean
block_html cache cleaned
collections cache cleaned
config cache cleaned
config_api cache cleaned
config_api2 cache cleaned
config_monitoring cache cleaned
eav cache cleaned
ecomdev_phpunit cache cleaned
factfinder_search cache cleaned
full_page cache cleaned
layout cache cleaned
translate cache cleaned
```

**CSS/Javascript cache:**

As the CSS and Javascript cache is handled separately in Magento, Magerun has it as part of the *`media:cache:`* namespace. Both CSS/Javascript as well as the images cache can be cleared:

- `media:cache:image:clear`
- `media:cache:jscss:clear`

Comment: Media and CSS cache clear commands are:


    `n98-magerun.phar media:cache:image:clear`
    `n98-magerun.phar media:cache:jscss:clear`

Comment: @cmuench: sure, that namespace prefix of the command was in the description. I made this more clear now.

Comment: With `n98-magerun.phar media:cache:image:clear` I get: `[InvalidArgumentException] There are no commands defined in the "media:cache:image" namespace.`

Answer (score 1):

To flush cache using MageRun:

```
magerun cache:clean && magerun cache:flush
```

Comment: from the top of my head: If you run `cache:flush` you won't need to run `cache:clean`. the commad you name flushes all caches at once.

Comment: Do we need to install magerun?  i get magerun: command not found

Comment: yeah you need to run the magerun command: https://files.magerun.net/