# In a Clustered environment, can a Magento Frontend webserver use readonly harddrive?

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend

I have clustered Magento in Google Cloud, and i have 2 frontend webservers, 1 admin + nfs server (here it goes mystore/admin session) and 1 database.

Since files on frontend webserver are delivered from nfs to then via nfs share (only `/var` and `/media`) and lsyncd for rest of files, i was wondering if anyway admin people works only on `/admin` dedicated VM, frontend webserver only needs to read Magento files, correct?
Session and cache is inside Redis dedicated instaces on database VM

If answer is yes (and i asking this question here becouse i think is more a developer/magento question rather then ServerFault) i could just mount the NFS (`/admin` vm) vm harddisk where Magento is located in Read only mode directly to webservers.

thank you

Comment: As long as all the extensions you're going to use with your Magento installation are properly written, this (`/var` & `/media`) should work. If session is not within redis, it will go into the database. Otherwise even if session goes to files, it's within `/var` so should never be a problem. Take care there is no directory named "magento" below `/tmp`.

Comment: so, it is possible for me to just have read-only harddisk on frontend servers, since they will not write to disk, correct?

Comment: Yes, that should normally be the case. The code and configuration should not be writeable in a properly set up server environment. The directories `/path/to/project/www/var` (Variable files—files whose content is expected to continually change during normal operation of the system—such as logs and cache files) and `/path/to/project/www/media` (media files like product images in diverse dimensions) need to be writeable for the server-user executing the code on. Perhaps it's not the best idea to run `/var` via NFS but you'll find out, give it a try. `/media` has far more reads than writes.

Comment: In my question, there are 2 different scenarios. actual-scenario is 2 frontend with magento on them via nfs+lsyncd, to-be-scenario is readonly hdd for frontend webserver. From @hakre answer is like you are concentrating on "nfs" scenario, whitch i tend to avoid...

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear to me, thanks for adding up. And it's not an answer, it's just a comment. And if you have the frontends read-only, then you have a problem as /var and /media is always expected to be writeable. I don't think that Magento will continue to properly work when you make these folder read-only, too.

Comment: Always expected to be writable by who exactly? This is what i need to clear up since cache and session are distributed in Redis and /admin has its own virtualmachin with write permission on all /path/to/magento

Comment: In Magento the [`var` directory follows the meaning in linux](http://www.linfo.org/var.html) and contains caches, logs, tmpfiles etc. Every extension can expect to be able to write operational data into it that is *not* accessible via HTTP. The `media` folder on the other hand is accessible via HTTP and contains for example generated [CSS and JS](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/73064/4115) files and also for different image sizes (e.g. see [*Get original image file from a cache URL*](http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/1005/4115)). Again extension authors can expect /media to be writeable.

Comment: As you can see this is more than just sessions. You also don't need to rely to my words, anyone with Magento expertise will say you the same. Problems only arise when some extensions are trying to write into *other* directories than `/var` or `/media` which is just bad practice. You normally should ban such extensions as they are of low quality. If you in your case want to try to not write anything into those two directories I think you've got quite some work in front of you to eliminate all write access into those two folders. But I never tried that.

Comment: We are getting close :). Let's isolate the 2 problems: 1) as a pure visitor on the store, so browsing pages, products and buying products, will this be enough to make magento write in ANY other folder rather then cache and session?

Comment: I'd say no but you can try to achieve that for your specific configuration. E.g. use a logging framework that replaces disk writes in there, use a media framework and/or procedures that replaces disk writes in there, use a js/css framework and/or procedures that replaces disk writes in there and so on and so forth. You have to try that your own, in part solutions (like storing session state) might already exist, but you have to wrap that up for your configuration.

Comment: Also you could make visible with the title of your quesiton that you're looking to use a read-only webserver for the the Shop-Frontend, not the Adminhtml-Backend.